# Perl Net::Telnet sending "YES"

Tags: perl, ftp, telnet

I want to send the next command to a system: "ZIAA:USR::ACCESS=COM,::FTP=W:;"

That is not difficult at all:

`$telnet->cmd("ZIAA:USR::ACCESS=COM,::FTP=W:;");`

The answer from the system to this comand is:

```
LOADING PROGRAM VERSION 16.5-0

EXECUTION STARTED


YOU ARE MODIFYING EXISTING PROFILE: USR    


CONFIRM COMMAND EXECUTION: Y/N ? |
```

As you can see the answer from the system to the command has several lines (included empty lines)

My question is: How Can I answer with "Y" and "enter"

My first attempt was:

```
$telnet->waitfor('/CONFIRM COMMAND EXECUTION: Y/N ? /');
$telnet->print("Y");
```

but it doesnt work at all, I suppose the waitfor should match with the whole text besides I dont know if the `"$telnet->print("Y");"` is the right way to say "YES" to the question.

When I answer to the question manually, I should write the char "Y" and then I press "enter". The answer from the system is "COMMAND EXECUTED", as you can see below:

```
LOADING PROGRAM VERSION 16.5-0

EXECUTION STARTED



YOU ARE MODIFYING EXISTING PROFILE: USR    



CONFIRM COMMAND EXECUTION: Y/N ? Y

COMMAND EXECUTED
```

Comment: According to the docs that should work, but your pattern is bad. The stuff you put into `waitfor()` is supposed to _look_ like a pattern (as in regex). So the `/` you have in the middle is breaking it. Try with escaping: `$telnet->waitfor( '/EXECUTION: Y\/N/' )`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but it didnt work =(. Ive tried with the following patterns:                                                                             $telnet->waitfor('/EXECUTION:Y\/N/');
$telnet->print("Y");
 
$telnet->waitfor('/EXECUTION: Y\/N/');
$telnet->print("Y");
 
$telnet->waitfor('/EXECUTION: Y\/N ?/');
$telnet->print("Y");                                                                                        is there any simbol to replace a blank space in the pattern of the WAITFOR? or do you have other idea? Thank you so much for your answer

Comment: Try with just `'/CONFIRM/'`.

Comment: Ive tried with waitfor('/CONFIRM/') but it didnt work. But .. How can I be sure that $telnet->print("Y");  is ok? or there might be another way to send "Y" trought telnet? could be $telnet->cmd("Y");? although I tested it and it doesnt work... Any other idea? Thank you so much for your answer and knowledge